# Clone a SSIS Data flow via C#

Tags: c#, ssis

I've created a Package with a SSIS Data flow (Designer mode) named 'User', witch have a ADO.NET source from table 'User' to a ADO.NET Destination table 'UserDest' (columns: id, name). Table columns are identically. Then I have to re-create this same structure of Dataflow to other 100 remaining tables (Creating precedence constraints aditionally, because the import must be done one table per time).
My idea is to edit the Package via C#, Clone the structure of the 'User' Data flow, adjust the columns mapping and the ADO.NET table source and destination.

I've started creating a Package variable to start cloning the properties, but the InnerObject returns null:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Gerador
    {
        public string RunPackage2()
        {
            var pkgLocation = @"C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\SSISExample1\SSISExample1\Package.dtsx";

            Application app = new Application();
            Package pkg = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation, null);
            var importUsersHost = pkg.Executables[0] as TaskHost;

            var pipe = importUsersHost.InnerObject as MainPipe; // Here it returns null

            Console.WriteLine();
            return "OK";
        }
    }
}
```

In resume, I need to generate 100 other Data flows like the 'Users' Data flow, and add a connector one after other (because each Data flow must run one by one).

[Dataflow image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiyDC.png)

[Package image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oHAN.png)

Answer (score 0):

The best approach for you to go about is to use BIML to accomplish this task. You can start with this series - [link](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/100550/)

Answer (score 0):

Marcelo,

I would check if the first element in the Executables is actually a data flow task or not. What happens if you try accessing the element with the name? Like Executables["my_data_flow_name"] ?

Alternatively, I would ask you to try a tool that I wrote. It is simpler to use than using the Object Model directly. Look at [this](https://github.com/samskolli/Pegasus/blob/master/Pegasus.Demo/AdoNetSourceAndDestination.cs) example and replicate that.

If you dont wanna use the tool I wrote, you can look at the underlying source code in there and directly apply that to the SSIS Object Model. But you might find it easier to use the tool I wrote :-)

UPDATE: I edited my answer to show looping directly in the example and also how the precedence constraints can be added too.

Comment: Yes, the element index zero is the Executable I'm trying to get, because it have the name of the Data flow

Comment: Marcelo, is there a specific message that you can provide? Is the object pipe itself is null? Your package and dll versions match?

Comment: I didnt notice this, I dont know if my dll version match... I was generating a Package (design mode) for the SQL Server 2016 (13.0). The server is remote, and I have only the sql server 2014 instance installed in my development PC, and the 2016 SSMS to connect the 2016 remote instance. What should I do?

Comment: Check what child folders you have available in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap. If you see a folder that has "13" in it, then it would mean you have a 2016 version. If you do, then I would use that dll instead of the 2014. If you can install 2016 version of integration services, I would do it cos then you match your target. Otherwise, I would target the 2014 version of Integration Services